# AWK to print subnet 0.69.100.in-abc.def

Tags: linux, unix, networking, awk, printf

My requirement is to print a subnet 100.69.0.0/10 value to 0.69.100.in-abc.def.
I tried as below

```
echo ['100.69.0.0/10'] | awk -F'.'  '{print $3"."$2"."$1".in-abc.def."}'
```

but i got output like this

```
0.69.[100.in-abc.def.
```

How to get output using awk as below

```
0.69.100.in-abc.def.
```

Comment: Try `echo ['100.69.0.0/10'] | awk -F'.'  '{print $3"."$2"."$1".in-abc.def."}' |  tr -d '['`

Comment: @DigvijayS Awk is perfectly capable of removing the square bracket itself; `sub(/\[/, "")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good attempt and you were close, try following. With OP's approach we need to put `[` and `]` as field separator too, so that we could catch the exact needed values by OP.

```
echo ['100.69.0.0/10'] | 
awk -F"[].[']" 'BEGIN{OFS="."} {print $4,$3,$2,"in-abc.def."}'
```

OR in case your `echo` is printing `['100.69.0.0/10']` then try following(where we have `[`,`]`,`.`,`'` as field separators for `awk`):

```
echo "['100.69.0.0/10']" | 
awk -F"[].[']" 'BEGIN{OFS="."} {print $5,$4,$3,"in-abc.def."}'
```

***Improvement in OP's code(attempt):*** OP has added only `.` as field separator to make things easy we could add `[` and `]` too in field separators so that we could get the exact needed values.

***NOTE:*** 1st solution is assuming that OP's echo output is `[100.69.0.0/10]` which I believe could be wrong, OP's `echo` output may have `'` like `['100.69.0.0/10']`(when using `"` to cover `echo`'s output) in that case kindly use 2nd solution in above.

Comment: Or if you want to keep field separator as `.` itself and simply substitute `[` with null then try `echo ['100.69.0.0/10'] | awk -F'.' -v OFS="."  '{sub(/\[/,"",$1);print $3,$2,$1,"in-abc.def."}'`.

Comment: echo "['100.69.0.0/10']" | 
awk -F"[].[']" 'BEGIN{OFS="."} {print $5,$4,$3,"in-abc.def."}' This worked.

Comment: @celcoprab, sure, thanks for confirming, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 2):

How about doing it properly:

```
$ echo ['100.69.0.0/10'] | 
awk '
match($0,/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/) {           # match ip-ish looking string
    split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),t,/\./)         # split it on .
    printf "%s.%s.%s.in-abc.def.\n",t[3],t[2],t[1]  # printf it carefree
}'
```

Output

```
0.69.100.in-abc.def.
```